# Indexes of nearest neighbors using k-NN (class package) in R

Tags: r, algorithm, classification, knn

I'm using the *knn* function of the *class* package:

```
k <- knn(train = training, test = testset, cl = classes, k = 1, prob = TRUE)
```

Is there any way to obtain the indexes of the k nearest neighbors in the training data for a given example in the test set? I don't find anything about that in the documentation of the package! The knn function only returns the **classes** of the test examples and the **classification probabilities**, but not the indexes of the k nearest neighbors for each test example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is a well-asked question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a different package to do that. You need the FNN package in R and the function get.knn. You can read the documentation [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/FNN/docs/get.knn)

Here is a simple example:

```
library(FNN)
data <- cbind(1:100, 1:100)

a <- get.knn(data, k=3)
```

and you type this to get the 3 nearest neighbors' indices for each record:

```
> a$nn.index
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
  [1,]    2    3    4
  [2,]    1    3    4
  [3,]    2    4    1
  [4,]    3    5    2
  [5,]    6    4    3
  [6,]    5    7    4
  [7,]    6    8    5
  [8,]    9    7   10
  [9,]   10    8   11
 [10,]    9   11   12
 [11,]   12   10    9
```